# android: Does device admin apps get deleted after factory reset?

Tags: android, device-admin

i have an application that is a device admin and i was wondering if while an application still has device admin privileges, if a factory reset was preformed will the app get deleted, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think so. All apps get deleted but the data won't I would back up to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the app has device admin privileges, if you format your device or perform factory reset, the app will be deleted unless it was converted to system app and that needs root. :)

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on the way the application was installed.

- If Application was installed by User and then given Device Admin permissions then definitely the application will get removed after factory reset
- If Application was installed just after fresh factory reset through QRCode scanning, making device a work profile device then also application will get removed after factory reset
- If Application was installed just after fresh factory reset through QRCode scanning through Google Enterprise management, making device a work profile device then application will get removed after factory reset but will get automatically installed once Phone is switched ON again.